# Is it okay to use Firebase as function call like state if the data was change then call my server side (I used PHP) instead of Firebase as a database?

Tags: php, firebase

I want to use firebase just a function call just to use my existing database and just to have realtime changes in my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase can't magically add realtime functionality to an existing database. It actually has an entire backend infrastructure set up to enable its realtime functionality, which your database would be missing.

Some options:

1. Build your own realtime functionality on top of your current database.
2. Synchronize changes to your database with a copy of that data in Firebase, which you then use for updating realtime listeners.
3. Switch your data model over to Firebase completely.

And I guess the last option is:

4. Keep using your current database, without realtime options.

None of these is pertinently better or worse than the others, so pick whichever one makes most sense to you and be willing to change your mind along the way.

Comment: ok sure, actually I like the option no. 2 which I can do use the realtime listeners. thanks again.